# Moving to Switzerland with my EU Husband

Tags: eu, indian-citizens, switzerland, italian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen with long term Italian green card (family purpose), my husband is Italian. He recently got a Job in Switzerland and we will soon move from Milan to Canton of Bern. Since I do not yet have an European passport, I was wondering if anyone can help me if I will be able to still legally work and stay there ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will.  See https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/themen/fza_schweiz-eu-efta/eu-efta_buerger_schweiz/faq.html

> Who may apply for family members to join them and reside in Switzerland?
>
> - Spouses
> - Children or grandchildren who are under 21 years of age or who financially depend on the petitioner
> - Parent(s) and grandparent(s), provided that they financially depend on the petitioner (they must prove that they were dependent on the petitioner before entering Switzerland).
>   For students the entitlement to family reunification is limited to the spouse and children entitled to financial support.
>
> Under the terms of the AFMP, the right to family reunification is subject to the condition that housing be adequate to lodge the entire family.

> Are family members allowed to work in Switzerland?
>
> Spouses and children of EU/EFTA nationals who are admitted to Switzerland under family reunification are legally entitled to work regardless of their nationality.